# JMeter request params not populating managed bean

Tags: ajax, jsf, jmeter, javabeans, managed

I'm writing a JMeter script to test some ajax-based JSF 2.3 pages. I am able to authenticate and create a user session against my application, but when I attempt to provide data to a form, the input params I provide through JMeter are not populating my (ViewScoped) bean attributes. They do populate the Request Parameters however. I know this because I can see my values in the bean when I print this map:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        Map<String, String[]> paramMap = req.getParameterMap();
```

But my values don't appear in the bean's fields.

My test plan:

```
User Defined Variables
HTTP Cookie Manager
HTTP Header Manager
Regular Expression Manager
Thread Group
--Transaction Controller
----HTTP Sampler 1
----HTTP Sampler 2
----HTTP Sampler 3
----View Results Tree
```

I do have JSESSION cookies set up in the cookie manager and they work fine, I can authenticate and navigate to the form.

I know that JMeter doesn't handle ajax in the traditional way. I have JMeter set up to do a POST submission. However I also have some AJAX attributes, such as, I have my request header set for ajax:

```
X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

My request params match those from the Firefox Developers tool and they are:

```
javax.faces.source  trackingForm:ctlSubmit  true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:ctlSubmit  trackingForm:ctlSubmit  true    text/plain  true
trackingForm    trackingForm    true    text/plain  true
ctlDtFrom_input 10/02/2021  true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs:ctlDtTo_input 10/07/2021  true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs:ctlCheckThisWeek_input    on  true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs:ctlOrderStatus    A   true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs:ctlSearchNumSimple_focus      true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs:ctlSearchNumSimple_input  sCustPO true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs:searchAndOperAdv  All true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs:searchTermListAdv:0:ctlSearchNumAdv_focus     true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs:searchTermListAdv:0:ctlSearchNumAdv_input sCustPO true    text/plain  true
trackingForm:trackingTabs_activeIndex   1   true    text/plain  true
javax.faces.ViewState   ${jsfViewState} true    text/plain  true
javax.faces.partial.ajax    true    true    text/plain  true
javax.faces.partial.execute @all    true    text/plain  true
javax.faces.partial.render  trackingForm    true    text/plain  true
```

I used the Regex Manager to get the viewState and populate a variable which I then use in my request params. From what I can tell, comparing response and request, viewState seems to be working ok. One question  here, does viewState have to be the same across all responses/requests for the entire transaction controller (i.e. from login to the subsequent form submission?), or just two at a time?

Again, my main question is why is my Managed Bean not being populated, since I can clearly see the Request Params are reaching it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the values but they don't work as expected it means that you're not sending the same request as browser does.

Unfortunately it's not possible to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing the full request from the browser and from JMeter so I can only recommend using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) and compare the full request from the browser with the full request from JMeter.

Given the requests will be the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/)) - you should get the same (successful) response.

If you're able to successfully execute the request using browser you could just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

Comment: I made it work. The blazemeter Chrome plugin created a test that worked. I had to correlate a little with the regex extractor and adding the JSESSIONID headers, but it works now.